# PowerPoint hyperlinks

Tags: windows-7

For a presentation, I created two .PPT files: one in Portrait mode so a flowchart would fit, the other in normal Landscape mode. I created hyperlinks to navigate back and forth between the two, and put both files in a folder.  It works fine on my computer, but when I send it to others, the hyperlinks don’t work; they get a “Can’t find the file” pop-up.

What do I need to do so the hyperlinks will work on other computers?
thanks!

Comment: It depends on the hyperlink you used. If the path doesn't exist on the other person's computer, the hyperlink won't work. What hyperlink did you use?

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely because the links is trying to reach the file at a specific **absolute path**.

If you have your files, part1.pptx and part2.pptx at, let say c:\Users\Paul\Desktop, then the hyperlinks, if absolute, will be `c:\Users\Paul\Desktop\part1.pptx` and `c:\Users\Paul\Desktop\part2.pptx`

If now, let say *John* downloads these files they will (most likely) be located in `c:\Users\John\Downloads\part1.pptx` and `c:\Users\John\Downloads\part2.pptx`, and will therefore not works, since John is missing the files in the location of `c:\Users\Paul\Desktop`

If you use **relative pathes**, you will be providing the links as `\part1.pptx` or `\part2.pptx`, thus making the location on the different computers irrelevant, as long as the two files are in the same folder.

If part1.pttx is located in `c:\Users\Paul\Downloads\part1.pptx` on John's computer, Powerpoint on Johns computer will also interpret the relative link `\part2.pptx` as the location `c:\Users\Paul\Downloads\part2.pptx`

Here you can see an exaple of how an **absolute** path look like (check the Address-box)
[image: Image showing link with absolute path]

Here you can see an exaple of how an **relative** path look like (check the Address-box)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to know more about Absolute and Relative path for hyperlinks. The difference is quite important. Absolute path is a full path that points to exact the same location where the file located at your file system. But Relative path is a path that relative to the working directory or application or your project PowerPoint project file. So, as an example, let's say you have a folder on drive C called "My Very Spacial Project" and two .PPT file intro.ppt and main.ppt. So now you are using Absolute paths and it looks like this:

intro.ppt hyperlink path (forward as you said): C:\My Very Spacial Project\main.ppt
main.ppt hyperlink path (back as you said): C:\My Very Spacial Project\intro.ppt

The reason why problem occurs at another computers is because they simply don't have such a files at this paths. So when they press Forward or Back at your project, the system tries to find a file using a path you set and finally they see an error.

All that you have to do is to change you paths to relative ones just like this:

intro.ppt hyperlink path: main.ppt
main.ppt hyperlink path: intro.ppt

and this should work the way you want.